How to set url like values as key in Helm?
I have this values in a yaml for a helm chart:
controller:
   nodeSelector:
       node-role.kubernetes.io/master: 'true'

But I want to install the chart just using one command without the file.
I've tried this without result:
helm install A B \
    --set "controller.nodeSelector[0].node-role.kubernetes.io/master='true'"

zsh: zsh: command not found: --set
Seeing this I thought it was a problem of the terminal
bash: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field PodSpec.spec.template.spec.nodeSelector of type map[string]string

nodeSelector isn't an array and you don't need array syntax.  The real trick is that you need to escape the periods in the fqdn/name name ; maybe --set-string controller.nodeSelector.node-role\\.kubernetes\\.io/master=true.

I assume the problem is nodeSelector[0]. Having [0] makes Helm assume it is an array, but when looking at the yaml it doesn't look like an array. So try this instead:
helm install A B --set "controller.nodeSelector.node-role\\.kubernetes\\.io/master=true"

You will have to escape ..

Thanks! it turned to be a combination of @DavidMaze solution and yours --set-string "controller.nodeSelector.node-role\.kubernetes\.io/master=true"
